# Biblatex: Add keyword to a set (mcite) and to a cite command

Tags: biblatex, biber

I have to work with two separated bibliography. I found a very convenient choice by using `biblatex` with `biber` and adding keywords. But I also want to be use some sets of references, for that I use the `\mcite` command. To make it funnier, I also have a command to cite normative document.

My problem is that `\mcite` or `\parencitetitle` are not managed correctly: they are not appearing in the bibliography. I think that is due to the add of keywords, or more precisely to the its none addition to the references generated by these two commands.

Thus, here is my question: how can I add keywords to the reference generated by `\mcite` or `\parencitetitle` commands?

A MWE could be:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[hyperindex=false]{hyperref}

\usepackage[citestyle=alphabetic,
    bibstyle=alphabetic,
    mcite=true,
    subentry,
    backend=biber
    ]{biblatex}

\addbibresource[datatype=bibtex]{biblio.bib}
\addbibresource[datatype=bibtex]{references.bib}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{standard}{\usedriver{\newblock}{manual}%
    \usebibmacro{pageref}%
    \finentry}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\parencitetitle}[\mkbibparens]
{\boolfalse{citetracker}%
    \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
    \usebibmacro{prenote}}
{\ifciteindex
    {\indexfield{indextitle}}
    {}%
    %\printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}
    \printtext[bibhyperref]{\printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}}
{\multicitedelim}
{\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareSourcemap{
    \maps[datatype=bibtex, overwrite]{
        \map{
            \perdatasource{./biblio.bib}
            \step[fieldset=KEYWORDS, fieldvalue=primary, append]
        }
        \map{
            \perdatasource{./references.bib}
            \step[fieldset=KEYWORDS, fieldvalue=secondary, append]
        }
    }
}

\usepackage{notes2bib}
    \bibnotesetup{keyword-entry={secondary,}}

\begin{document}
Eurocode: \parencitetitle{en1998}

\mcite{set1,*Boncella1984,*Tilley1982} This is some nice text I want to cite as a set.
\bibnote{some added text:\mcite{set1,*Boncella1984,*Tilley1982}}

Here I cite a single paper from the previous set.\cite{Tilley1982} This is how it should look like with included note.\bibnote{more added text: \fullcite{set1}}

Another set cite\mcite{set2,*Tilley1982,*Boncella1984}

And a reference from the second file.\cite{NE1}

\printbibliography[keyword=primary]
\newrefcontext[sorting=none]
\printbibliography[title=References, keyword=secondary]
\end{document}
```

The file `biblio.bib`:

```
@STANDARD{en1998,
  shorttitle = {EN 1998},
  title = {EN 1998, Eurocode 8: contruction norms},
  organization = {CEN},
  address = {Brussels, Belgium},
  year = {2005},
}

@article{Boncella1984,
author = {Boncella, James M. and Andersen, Richard A.},
journal = {Inorg. Chem.},
pages = {432--437},
volume = {23},
year = {1984}
}

@article{Tilley1982,
author = {Tilley, T. Don and Andersen, Richard},
journal = {J. Am. Chem. Soc.},
pages = {1772--1774},
volume = {104},
year = {1982}
}
```

And the `references.bib` file:

```
@report{NE1,
     author = {Doe, Joe},
     title = {A super document},
     year = {2017},
 }
```

I think that the warnings given by pdflatex or another compiler can be useful to understand the problem.

PS: Optional questions are about the warning :"Field 'entryset' is no longer needed in set member entries in Biber", how can I fix it properly ?
Is it the reason why the subentries generated by `\bibnote{more added text: \fullcite{set1}}` are not well numbered ( a,b,...) ?

Comment: Re the PS: https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/812

Comment: I'll have a closer look at this soon, but is there any chance you could make your MWE a bit more *M*? Do you really need all `.bib` entries to show the issue? Does the MWE need all redefinitions and all `biblatex` options? The question would look much more welcoming if the code was a bit shorter.

Comment: Thanks for this kind reminder I will try to minimise it.

Comment: I have fixed the file path issue and removed a few more unnecessary comments and new lines. Hope you are OK with that.

Comment: Yes, I was doing it in the same time I think. Thank you, for that. You are right, a little clean up was necessary, I should have seen it before.

Comment: I can reproduce the issue with `\mcite` and I agree with your analysis, I will write up an answer with a suggestion shortly (hopefully). But I can't see an issue with `\parencitetitle`. What's wrong with it.

Comment: I am very grateful for your work on `\mcite`. About `\parencitetitle`, you mean that the keywords are correctly added but it is still not printed ?

Comment: As far as I can see you only use `\parencitetitle` on `en1998` in the MWE. That entry is printed in the reference section for me (as well it should, because it comes from `biblio.bib` and thus has the `primary` key). The only issue that I can see is that the label only shows "[05]" which is not pretty, but expected. I would use something like `shorthand = {EN 1998}` in which case one can probably do away with `\parencitetitle` altogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your bibliographies are filtered by `keyword`s. `keyword`s are affixed to an entry via the `.bib` file and the `keywords` field. In your case that is done automatically by a sourcemap based on the `.bib` file.

With `\mcite{set1,*Boncella1984,*Tilley1982}` you create an entry `set1` (essentially on the fly in the document) that is not part of any `.bib` file and thus has no keywords. Hence `set1` does not appear in the bibliography when you filter for entries with a specific keyword.

With the current interface it seems impossible to fix a `keyword` to `set1`, but in theory and with a bit of low-level hackery that might be possible. I however don't believe you have to go that far.

#### Use `notkeyword`

You don't actually need the `primary` keyword, you could use `notkeyword=secondary` to exclude all secondary entries, which would allow the sets to go into the 'primary' bibliography.

```
\printbibliography[notkeyword=secondary]
\newrefcontext[sorting=none]
\printbibliography[title=References, keyword=secondary]
```

#### Use bibliography categories

As mentioned above `keyword`s are quite static because the usually come from the datasource itself (in your case, they are slightly more dynamic thanks to the sourcemap, but ultimately they depend on the `.bib` file as well). The dynamic/on-the-fly counterpart for keyword filtering is category filtering. Bibliography categories are created on the fly in the document, just like the set entries from `\mcite`.

```
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{primary}
\addtocategory{primary}{set1,set2}

\defbibfilter{primary}{keyword=primary or category=primary}

\begin{document}
\mcite{set1,*Boncella1984,*Tilley1982} This is some nice text I want to cite as a set.
\bibnote{some added text:\mcite{set1,*Boncella1984,*Tilley1982}}

Here I cite a single paper from the previous set.\cite{Tilley1982} This is how it should look like with included note.\bibnote{more added text: \fullcite{set1}}

Another set cite\mcite{set2,*Tilley1982,*Boncella1984}

And a reference from the second file.\cite{NE1}

\printbibliography[filter=primary]
\newrefcontext[sorting=none]
\printbibliography[title=References, keyword=secondary]
\end{document}
```

Would filter primary sources by means of `keyword`s and categories for `\mcite`s.

Comment: It's a nice work about the `\mcite`. But there is still something strange on my machine about `\parencitetitle`: the reference `en1998`  is appearing in the text but not in the bilbiographies. I get the warning :`name{cite.0@en1998} has been referenced but does not exist, replaced by a fixed one`.

Comment: @R.N I ignored the `en1998` issue in my answer because I could not reproduce it as I mentioned in my earlier comment under the question. It is very likely not directly related to the `\mcite` issue anyway, so I suggest you ask a new question about that issue, focussing only on `\parencitetitle`. Minimise the code example further to only deal with `en1998` and the associated problems. As mentioned in the comments `en1998` appears in the bibliography for me.

Comment: I finally found the source of the problem with `\parencitetitle`, I will ask a new question.